AWS Python Lambda - Package Size & Cold Starts
I was wondering whether someone here shared the same experience.

I have a Python Lambda which runs some “simple” requests for recommending images based on a vector database (qdrant). The package itself already has a size of 65MB  (e.g. qdrant client and firebase).
Although I turned on provisioned concurrency I still have cold starts of roughly 5 seconds. I even created a dummy lambda which has no imports and responds a 200 immediately and has the same packages installed -  still 5 sec cold start. Using loggings I triple checked that provisioned concurrency is utilized.
I am thinking about a complete rewrite in TypeScript of the Lambda to handle these cold starts.

Do you have the same experiences regarding Python Lambdas? Is there a neat trick I am not aware of?

Is your lambda in a VPC? You can create another simple lambda to ping your main lambda every minute via cloudwatch events or eventsbridge to keep it warm.
Or, just use an ec2 or fargate.
Rewriting in typescript should help but if you can do it in Rust or Go, it's even better.

Thanks for your answer. Using another Lambda to ping it or EC2 nullifies the point of actually using a Lambda. With another programming language and Provisioned Concurrency, there should be no issue. I am just frustrated that Python packaging is so large and I still got cold starts.

Unclear how moving from Python to TS/JS is going to improve the situation here. Aren't you simply reliant on very large third-party imports? Would their TS/JS equivalent be significantly smaller?

Actually yes, that's what I am hoping for. On PyPi the qdrant client has something like 0.2 MB but in the Lambda it is contributing roughly 25MB. I do not know how the packaging works in detail but I am hoping and expecting that the NodeJS packages are way smaller. Also I am confused why Provisioned Concurrency is still resulting in these long cold starts in this scenario.

In lamdba, packages are complied everytime, so it can take sometime. but as it's expeced initialization time nothing more we can do on that.
Thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
